# Trying to simplify the following boolean expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

**Simplify:**

$y \times [x + (x' \times y)]$

My attempt:

1. $y \times [(x + x') \times (x + y)] \quad \textit{First Distributive Axiom} $
2. $y \times [1 \times (x + y)] \quad \textit{First Inverse Axiom} $

*And for the continued steps, I am unfortunately stuck again.*

**Axioms available:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see $yy=y$ directly in the axioms you have, but it follows from $yy=y(y+0)=y$.  And so

$$
y(x + x'y)=yx+yx'y=yx+yyx'=yx+yx'=y(x+x')=y(1)=y.
$$

Comment: Hi, I am confused by what you've written. Can you please demonstrate step by step? What have I done wrong?

Comment: What you did is fine… possibly even more clear than my answer.  You can apply Identity next, to get $y(x+y)$, and finally Absorption to get $y$.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

1. $y \times [(x + x') \times (x + y)] \quad \textit{First Distributive Axiom} $
2. $y \times [1 \times (x + y)] \quad \textit{First Inverse Axiom} $
3. $y(x+y) \quad \textit{Identity Axiom} $
4. $yx + yy \quad \textit{Distributive Axiom} $
5. $(yx) + y \quad \textit{Idempotent Axiom} $
6. $y + (yx) \quad \textit{Commutative Axiom} $
7. $y \quad \textit{Absorption Axiom} $

Comment: I believe step 3 should be $y(x+y)$; otherwise 100%.

Comment: @mjqxxxx what is "100% otherwise"?

Comment: Other than that small typo, you are 100% correct.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, this is wrong. Why are you misleading me?